# Store post in raw markdown format, no html?

Tags: plugins, rest-api, markdown

Is it possible to store posts in pure markdown format? so that I can retrieve the content through the REST API and get the markdown code, without any added html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );` to remove the added HTML tags.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop

Comment: Where do I put this code? Please, for someone that is not a WP expert this is not obvious...

Comment: Per the referenced link, you'd put in your theme's functions.php file:

**Disabling the filter**

Some people choose to disable the wpautop filter from within their theme’s **functions.php**:

`remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );`

There’s also a [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpautop-control/) available to enable/disable the filter on a post-by-post basis.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do two things

1. Completely disable visual editor
2. enable Markdown.

**Disable Visual editor:** Add this code in the themes function.php file or as a plugin.

```
add_filter( 'user_can_richedit' , '__return_false', 50 );
```

**Enable Markdown:** Install this plugin [Wp-Markdown](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-markdown/)

Comment: With or without the plugin activated, if I paste markdown content on the post, I get paragraph html tags thorough the text. Indeed no difference with the plugin, maybe it's not working in the final WP version?

Comment: You must disable the richtext editor. Also wordpress has a function named "wpautop" which renders html <p> tag automatically. You have to disable that too. use this in your function file remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );